# encode hash in utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I want to substitude a substring with a hash - said substring contains non-ascii caracters, so I tried to encode it to UTF-8.

```
result = re.sub(r'(Start:\s*)([^:]+)(:\s*)([^:]+)', lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3) + hashlib.sha512(m.group(4).encode()).hexdigest(), line.encode('utf-8'))
```

I am not realy sure why this doesn't work, I thought with line.encode('utf-8'), the whole string is getting encoded.
I also tried to encode my m.groups to UTF-8, but I got the same UnicodeDecodeError.

> [unicodedecodeerror: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte in position
>   ordinal not in range(128)]

Sample input:

```
Start: myUsername: myÜsername:
```

What am I missing ?

**EDIT_**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/coding/filter.py", line 26, in <module>
    encodeline = line.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 112: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Could you please post the example input and the stacktrace of the error you mention? (generally, your question does not seem to be [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: your are right, sorry - I put in some more information

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3 code? I strongly suspect your problem is that you're running on Python 2, and trying to `encode` a `str` (which is a largely nonsensical thing to do). A full traceback and a [MCVE] would be helpful. Lastly, to be sure, split up the line so you only `encode` once per line, e.g. `encodedline = line.encode('utf-8')`, then replace `line.encode('utf-8')` in the `re.sub` with `encodedline` so you aren't able to confuse which `encode` is the problem.

Comment: I am running python 2.7 - is there a way to solve this problem or should I go with the "hack" ?

Comment: @peacemaker: The hack is a bad idea (`setdefaultencoding` is deleted from `sys` after calling it for a reason; changing the default mid-run risks all sorts of problems from various libraries that may have cached the encoding, or the results of encoding things in it, and suddenly find that things aren't behaving the way they did at startup). I strongly suspect your code will work by deleting all calls to `encode` in that line; you already *had* UTF-8 encoded data, so trying to `encode` it again was the source of your problems. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009825/364696).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your symptoms, you're running on Python 2. Calling `encode` on a Python 2 `str` is almost always nonsensical.

You have two problems; one you're hitting now, and one you'll hit if you fix your current code.

Your first problem is **`line` is *already* a `str` in (apparently) UTF-8 encoded bytes**, not `unicode`, so `encode`ing it implicitly *decodes* with Python's default encoding (ASCII; this isn't locale specific to my knowledge, and it's a rare Python 2 install that uses anything else), *then* re-encodes with the specified codec (or the default if not specified). Basically, `line` was already UTF-8 encoded, you told it to encode *again* as UTF-8, but that's nonsensical, so Python tried to `decode` as ASCII first, and failed before it even tried to `encode` as you instructed.

**The solution to this problem is to just not `encode` `line` at all**; it's already UTF-8 encoded, so you're already golden.

Your second problem (which you haven't encountered yet, but you will) is that you're calling `encode` on the `group(4)` result. But of course, since the input was a `str`, the group is a `str` too, and you'll encounter the same problem trying to `encode` a `str`; since the group came from raw UTF-8 encoded bytes, the non-ASCII parts of it cause a `UnicodeDecodeError` during the implicit decode step before the encode.

The reason:

```
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

works is that it (dangerously) changes the implicit decode step to use UTF-8, so all your `encode` calls now perform the implicit `decode` with UTF-8 instead of ASCII; the `decode` and `encode` is mostly pointless, since all it does is return the original `str` after confirming it's legal UTF-8 by means of `decode`ing it as such, and otherwise acting as an expensive no-op.

To fix the second problem, just change:

```
m.group(4).encode()
```

to:

```
m.group(4)
```

That leaves your final code as:

```
result = re.sub(r'(Start:\s*)([^:]+)(:\s*)([^:]+)',
                lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3) + hashlib.sha512(m.group(4)).hexdigest(),
                line)
```

Optionally, if you want to confirm your expectation that `line` is in fact UTF-8 encoded bytes already, add the following *above* that `re.sub` line:

```
try:
    line.decode('utf-8')
except Exception as e:
    sys.exit("line (of type {!r}) not decodable as UTF-8: {}".format(line.__class__.__name__, e))
```

which will cause the program to exit immediately if the data given is not legal UTF-8 (and will also let you know what type `line` is, so you can confirm for sure if it's really `str` or `unicode`, since `str` implies you chose the wrong codec, while `unicode` means your inputs aren't of the expected type).

Answer (score 0):

I found .. in my eyes a  workaround. 
Doesn't feel right though, but it does the job.

```
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

I thought it could be done with .encode('utf-8')

Comment: This is only a hack, but not the real solution. But we can't help without knowing more about your string etc

Answer (score 0):

```
file = 'xyz'
res = hashlib.sha224(str(file).encode('utf-8)).hexdigest()
```

Because of unicode object must be encode as string before hash.